# How can I summarize a count() of multiple tables and include a 0 instead of null when no rows are returned

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to count the number of rows that have been generated today across multiple tables, then summarize this information in a table with the source table name and the count. I have been able to do this using `union withsource`.

However, if no rows are returned from a table then it is missed out of the summary. Instead I want to return a count of 0 if there are no rows and still include the table in the summary. Is this possible?

I think I need `make-series` but I can't figure out how to format the query.

#### Example

Today is: 2022-11-21

**TableOne**

| RowId | TimeGenerated |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-21 |
| 2 | 2022-11-21 |
| 3 | 2022-11-19 |

**TableTwo**

| RowId | TimeGenerated |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-19 |
| 2 | 2022-11-18 |

**Kusto**

```
union withsource=source TableOne, TableTwo
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(1d)
| summarize dcount(TimeGenerated) by source
```

**Actual Output**

| source | dcount_TimeGenerated |
| --- | --- |
| TableOne | 2 |

**Desired Output**

| source | dcount_TimeGenerated |
| --- | --- |
| TableOne | 2 |
| TableTwo | 0 |

Comment: The data does not match the results.

Comment: `dcount(TimeGenerated)` does not make any sense when you're filtering on a single day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set query_now = datetime(2022-11-22);
let TableOne = view()
{
   datatable(RowId:int, TimeGenerated:datetime)
   [
       1 ,datetime(2022-11-21)
      ,2 ,datetime(2022-11-21)
      ,3 ,datetime(2022-11-19)
   ] 
};
let TableTwo = view()
{
   datatable(RowId:int, TimeGenerated:datetime)
   [
       1 ,datetime(2022-11-18)
      ,2 ,datetime(2022-11-17)
   ]
};
union withsource=source TableOne, TableTwo
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(3d)
| summarize dcount(TimeGenerated) by source
| join kind=rightouter datatable(source:string)["TableOne", "TableTwo"] on source
| project source = source1, dcount_TimeGenerated = coalesce(dcount_TimeGenerated, 0)
```

| source | dcount_TimeGenerated |
| --- | --- |
| TableOne | 2 |
| TableTwo | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA7WQXWvDIBiF7/MrXnKlYKHai20d2e3Y1WDkrpSSxpfELtHNmEn38d9nlg8aWno3BRXP8fhwGnTw3qI97rTxkIDMHDpVIxFLIRacL4Sg91EVXGm2r/BZYzB9KPSERl8RQPcgzCCRF%20Of5FppxyANCY%20o0YY0uR4zaeffdEs3OLDzzzgdZCauy6sLMr/7k7cQ/Zwgp978JzK/vYrMb3qmDqnVymjwypWNaW2OSb9NzbIJOPoGX6LFORU8JJAVhqwkDYamrevMqk8EmZtWOzLzUtgfoc8P3oNRGl6VlolVRelM69Ce1ND71o2zShd0E49AMYN4RIq3EOCnxDdrDpi74SIU3B84G2h2c/IEcpNV2ORILukMlvQXpvMVRooCAAA=)

Comment: This does seem to do the job. I've actually added more tables and replaced dcount with a regular count based on the feedback. I'll happily accept the answer but it might be useful if you explain a little about why it works in the answer. Thank you!

Comment: If you union 100 tables but only one table has data, you are going to see only one record in the result set. The summarize operator is not aware of your data sources, it generates a result row per aggregation key. If we want to verify that we get a row per data source, we need to create those rows.